# Как при сохранения данных в CSV добавить текущее время в имя файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Я сохраняю данные в CSV:

```
exact = pd.DataFrame(exact, columns=['dicclientid','code', 'user_name','action_date'])
exact.to_csv('exact.csv', sep=';')
```

Как в название файла всегда добавлять текущее время?

Answer (score 4):

Например:

```
from datetime import datetime

...

# Пример: exact_02042019_130203.csv
file_name = 'exact_{}.csv'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S"))

exact.to_csv(file_name, sep=';')
```

---

Таблицу с форматами даты можно посмотреть тут: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант похожий на [ответ @gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/964424/211923), но с использованием [Literal String Interpolation (PEP 498)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) для Python 3.6+:

```
In [287]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [288]: file_name = f'exact_{DT.now():%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M}.csv'

In [289]: print(file_name)
exact_2019-04-02_12-06.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) - эквивалент `datetime` в Pandas.

```
current_time = pd.Timestamp('now').strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
fname = 'exact_{}.csv'.format(current_time)
exact.to_csv(fname, sep=';')
```